# Google play protect is preventing the installation of my debug apk

Tags: android, debugging, testing, apk

I'm working on a project and until recently all my debug apks were working perfectly fine whenever I test them. However, when I tried to install my latest debug apk googleplay protect prevented the installation. This is the first time it happens. I can't figure out why since I built it the same way I built my previous apks. Although previous apks work fine. Now whenever I need to build a debug apk I have to disable google play protect.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore that and there might be an arrow button which when clicked is going to give you another button saying `Continue anyway` and you can install it easily again.

Also, make sure you are accepting apks from `Unknown sources` which can be changed in settings.